# Se puede usar [OutputCache] en una aplicacion Razor pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

Tengo una aplicacion Razor Pages y quisiera utilizar el atributo [OutputCache],
pero parace que no funciona.
Lo puse en la cabecera de la clase y tambien probé en el evento OnGet pero no pasa nada.

La configuracion es la siguiente:
En el program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddOutputCache(o => {
    o.AddBasePolicy(builder => builder.Cache());
    o.AddPolicy("adriancache", x => x.Expire(TimeSpan.FromDays(1)).Tag("adriancache") );
});

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseOutputCache();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

luego en el codigo de una pagina:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[OutputCache(PolicyName = "adriancache")]    
public class InventarioModel : PageModel
{
    ...........
}
```

y tambien probe sobre el OnGet() pero no funciona.
Tal vez no esta disponible para estas aplicaciones, busque por todos lados pero siempre se refieren a controladores MVC.
gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si es posible y el atributo `[OutputCache]` debe agregarse en la clase como indica la [documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/output?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

> For apps with controllers, apply the [OutputCache] attribute to the
> action method. **For Razor Pages apps, apply the attribute to the
> Razor page class**.

En la misma documentación hay una nota al principio que dice

> - In apps that use CORS middleware, UseOutputCache must be called after UseCors.
> - In Razor Pages apps and apps with controllers, UseOutputCache must be called after UseRouting.
> - Calling AddOutputCacheand UseOutputCache doesn't start caching behavior, it makes caching available. Caching response data must be
>   configured as shown in the following sections.

Muchas configuraciones que se realizan en el `program.cs` requieren que se establezcan en un orden determinado (es un problema muy tipico, por eso lo señalo).

Te dejo un ejemplo a partir de la plantilla básica.

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

        //Agregar el AddOutputCache
        builder.Services.AddOutputCache(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("policy", builder =>
                builder.Expire(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));
        });
        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapRazorPages();

        //Agregar esto
        app.UseOutputCache();

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

index.cshtml

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    La fecha es: @DateTime.Now.ToString("T")
</div>
```

index.cshtml.cs

```
[OutputCache(PolicyName = "policy")]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

        
    public void OnGet()
    {
         
    }
}
```

Este código mostrará
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al presionar repetidamente <kbd>F5</kbd> verás que la hora solo cambia luego de 10 segundos

Comment: Es exactamente lo que hice, fijate el codigo que puse de exemplo.

Comment: En teoria, el OnGet() no deberia ejecutarse, o sí?

Comment: Se que es casi lo mismo, pero tu pregunta apunta a si es posible o no, mas que a determinar porque lo tuyo no funciona. Además señalaste que no has encontrado información al respecto, te he puesto la documentación y un ejemplo que funciona (probado antes de publicar)

Comment: El OnGet() NO se ejecuta hasta que pasa el tiempo configurado. Una vez pasado de ese tiempo vuelve a entrar a la función

Comment: Al OnGet le puse un Console.WriteLine que se ejecuta siempre, o sea, el cache no funciona. No encuentro la causa.

Comment: Estoy confundido, si querías saber el motivo por el cual no te funciona, porque sencillamente no preguntaste eso??